# Edit JavaFX SceneBuilder's sample data

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

In SceneBuilder there is an option (`View -> Show/Hide Sample Data`) to show/hide sample data for e.g. `ListViews` or `Charts`.

My question is if there is a way to modify or provide these data, to get a better impression of the result.

Tanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample data appear to be pretty much baked into the code. (Have a look at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/src/ef68e38ec242/src/main/java/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/fxom/sampledata/?at=default).) So unless you want to fork this and build your own version, I don't think there's a way to do it. You could also [submit a feature request](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues?status=new&status=open).